# PostgreSQL field data type for IPv4 addresses

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip

What is the correct data type for IPv4 addresses in PostgreSQL?

I heard about `inet`, but never used it.

I need to perform `SELECT` queries like `SELECT ... WHERE ip = '99.88.99.88'` and it should support the output of human readable format (by human readable I mean '99.88.99.88').

It would be nice to have the ability to `SELECT` the IP addresses by there subnet.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The built-in `cidr` and `inet` types will do what you want and provide suitable operators:

```
regress=> SELECT '192.168.1.19'::inet << '192.168.1.0/24'::cidr;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

See the PostgreSQL documentation on [network datatype operators and functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html) and on the [network datatypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html).

Limited index support is provided for the `cidr` and `inet` types; in particular, 'address in range' type queries are turned into range queries at least where the address is a constant. See [this (rather old) thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CC17A70CE630D7119C520090278444C81248B7@mail1.gomez.com).

See also Chris's point re `ip4r`.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html having field of `inet` type it is only what you need.

> The operators <<, <<=, >>, and >>= test for subnet inclusion.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add that the built-in types are quite powerful, and that's where you should start.  However if you need GIN indexing, check out http://pgfoundry.org/projects/ip4r/

A case for ip4r (why I started using it) might be if you need to store CIDR blocks and make sure that no block contains any other block.  Since this requires GIN indexing, you have to go with ip4r rather than the built-in types.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there were GIN or GiST indexes for IP ranges but didn't find them in a quick search.

Comment: I discovered the hard way (trying to use exclusion constraints) that GIN was not supported and was lead to ip4r by the author.